# node.js / express app - which async method to use to replace my nested calls to HGET?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

**Background**

I'm just learning node js and have run into a situation where I need to make up to two back to back calls to my redis database, depending on the results of the first query.

The code I have right now works.. but it's very ugly.  I wrote it this way because I'm not good with async 'stuff'.  But now that it's working... I want to refactor in a way that is readable and of course, in a way that works.

Here's the code, along with an explanation of what I'm trying to do:

**Code**

```
  router.get('/:ip', function(req, res, next) {
        var ip = req.params.ip;
        if ( ! validate_ipV4(ip) ) {
                res.status(400).send("Invalid IP");
                return;
        }

        var three_octets = extract_octets(ip, 3);
        var two_octets = extract_octets(ip, 2);
        if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'emergency router.get() attempting hget using :' + three_octets); }
        redis.hget("e:" + three_octets, 'ccid', function (e, d) {
                if (e){
                        winston.log('error', 'hget using key: ' + octets + ' failed with error: ' + e);
                        res.status(500).send("Database query failed");
                        return;
                }
                if (d) {
                        if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'HGET query using ip: ' + ip + ' returning data: ' + d ) };
                        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(d));
                        return;
                } else {
                        //retry using only 2 octets
                        redis.hget("e:" + two_octets, 'ccid', function (e, d) {
                                if (e){
                                        winston.log('error', 'hget using key: ' + octets + ' failed with error: ' + e);
                                        res.status(500).send("Database query failed");
                                        return;
                                }
                                if (d) {
                                        if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'HGET query using ip: ' + ip + ' returning data: ' + d ) };
                                        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(d));
                                        return;

                                }else {
                                        res.status(404).send("Unknown IP");
                                        return;
                                }
                        });//end hget
                }
        });//end hget

});
```

**Explanation:**

Accept an ip address as input.  10.1.1.1

Try to query the database for a hash that matches the first three octets.  For example:  "hget e:10.1.1 ccid"

If i have a match, I can return the db results and exit.  otherwise, if the query came back with no results, then I need to retry using the first two octets:   "hget e:10.1 ccid"

if that returns nothing, then i can exit the GET method.

**ASYNC**

I know that there is an async module... and i've tried to use MAP before.  But from what I understand, you cannot force MAP to exit early. 
So for example, if I did something like this:

```
  async.map(ipOctets, hash_iterator, function (e, r) { 
  })
```

where ipOctets was an array with both 10.1.1. and 10.1 in it, if the first query found a match in the database, there's no way I can stop it from running the second query.

Can you give me some pointers on how to improve this code so that I don't have to repeat the same code twice?

I also thought of putting the redis.hget call into a separate function... like this:

```
var hash_get = function (hash, key, field) {
        if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'hash_get() invoked with : ' + hash + ' ' + key + ' ' + field);}
        redis.hget(hash + key, field, function (e, d) {
                if (e){
                        winston.log('hash_get() failed with: ' + e);
                        return 500;
                }
                if (d) {
                        return (d);
                }else {
                        return 404;
                }
        });
}
```

But again, I'm not sure how to do the following in a synchronous way:

- call it from router.get
- check results
- repeat if necessary

Sorry for the noob questions.. but any pointers would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

Since posting, i found this http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#some
and I'm currently testing to see if this will work for me.

But please comment if you have some suggestions!
Thanks.

Comment: One side note is that you don't need explicit `return` statements when you have `if/else` combination. `if { /* do stuff */ return; } else { /* ... */ }`, the `return` doesn't do anything useful there

Comment: Have you looked at using promises instead of callbacks?

Comment: @PeterGelderbloem I will take a look @ promises.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
router.get('/:ip', function (req, res, next) {
    var ip = req.params.ip;
    if (!validate_ipV4(ip)) {
        res.status(400).send("Invalid IP");
        return;
    }

    var three_octets = extract_octets(ip, 3);
    var two_octets = extract_octets(ip, 2);
    //if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'emergency router.get() attempting hget using :' + three_octets); }

    var hash = "e:"
    var field = 'ccid';

    async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        hash_get(hash, three_octets, field, callback)
    },
    function (d, callback) {
        if (d) {
            callback(null, d);
            return;
        }

        hash_get(hash, two_octets, field, callback)
    }
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            winston.log('error', err.message);
            res.status(err.status).send(err.message);
            return;
        }
        if (result) {
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result));
            return;
        }
        res.status(404).send("Unknown IP");
        return;
    });
});

var hash_get = function (hash, key, field, callback) {
    if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'hash_get() invoked with : ' + hash + ' ' + key + ' ' + field); }
    redis.hget(hash + key, field, function (e, d) {
        if (e) {
            callback({ status: 500, message: 'hget using key: ' + key + ' failed with error: ' + e });
            return;
        }

        if (d) {
            if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'HGET query using ip: ' + ip + ' returning data: ' + d) };
            callback(null, d);
        } else {
            callback(null, null);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) method which cascades functions into each other.  I really only like to use it when I have 3 nested callbacks or more, otherwise I don't feel like it simplifies it enough.

After looking at your code and seeing how much you can reuse I think I would use [async.until](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#until) though.

```
    router.get('/:ip', function(req, res, next) {
        var ip = req.params.ip;
        if (!validate_ipV4(ip)) {
            res.status(400).send("Invalid IP");
            return;
        }

        let success = false;
        let octets_num = 3;
        async.until(
            // Test this for each iteration
            function() { return success == true || octets < 2},  // You would adjust the test to set limits
            // Do this until above
            function(callback) {
                let octets = extract_octets(ip, octets_num);
                redis.hget("e:" + octets, 'ccid', function(e, d) {
                    if(e) {
                        winston.log('error', 'hget using key: ' + octets + ' failed with error: ' + e);
                        res.status(500).send("Database query failed");
                    }
                    else if(id) {
                        if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'HGET query using ip: ' + ip + ' returning data: ' + d ) };
                        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(d));
                        success == true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        octects_num--;
                    }
                    callback(null);
                });
            }
            // After success or not found within 3 or 2 octets
            function(err, result) {
                if(success == false) {
                    res.status(404).send("Unknown IP");
                    return;
                }

            }
        ...
    }
```

This permits you to reuse the same chunk of code with minimal variation.  It's rough and I don't have the rest of your application to test it, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your answer first but being the noob I am, I couldn't get it to work.  Once I deliver my code ( have a deadline to meet) I will revisit this and spend more time working this out.  I am interested in becoming a proficient node developer, so thanks very much for taking the time to answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  It might need some tweaking as I didn't have all of your application to test it.  It's a good technique for minimizing the amount of code you have to write (and oftentimes more importantly _rewrite_).  Best of luck!

Comment: do you need callback(null, success) ?

Comment: You do not.  The first parameter of the `callback` would be an error (hence the `null`).  Any additional parameters become parameters passed to the success function at the end, and you would do that if you needed to pass any data from the loop function to the success function.

Answer (score 0):

Check Async.waterfall() for this as you want the result of one callback into another (http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall).
Async.map could not be used as it will hit both the octets at the same time
which you don't want .

### Code

```
  router.get('/:ip', function(req, res, next) {
    var ip = req.params.ip;
    if ( ! validate_ipV4(ip) ) {
            res.status(400).send("Invalid IP");
            return;
    }

    var three_octets = extract_octets(ip, 3);
    var two_octets = extract_octets(ip, 2);
    var redis_hget=function(octets){
        redis.hget("e:"+octets,'ccid',function(e,d){
            callback(null,d)
        })
    }
    if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'emergency router.get() attempting hget using :' + three_octets); }
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            redis_hget(three_octets)
        },
        function(d,callback){
            if(d)
                callback(d)
            else
                redis_hget(two_octets)
        }
    ],function(err,result){
        if(err){
            winston.log('error', 'hget using key: ' + octets + ' failed with error: ' + e);
            res.status(500).send("Database query failed");
            return;
            }else{
                if(result){
                    if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'HGET query using ip: ' + ip + ' returning data: ' + d ) };
                    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(d));
                    return;
                }else{
                    res.status(404).send("Unknown IP");
                    return;
                }
            }
    })
}
```